Disable excel password popup in SSIS using C#
I need to check if the excel is password protected(without entering password) and set the variable value to YES. I tried using DisplayAlerts = false but it didn't work in SSIS, any other option to disable password popup while SSIS package is executing?
I can only use excel interop, can't install other extensions due to restrictions.
public bool IsExcelPasswordProtected(string InputFilePwdCheck)
{
    Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();            
    ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
    Excel.Workbook ExcelWorkbook = null;
    bool Protected = false;

    try
    {                
        ExcelWorkbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(InputFilePwdCheck);
        ExcelWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        Protected= false;
    }

    catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException)
    {                
        Protected= true;
    }

    finally
    {                
        ExcelWorkbook.Close();
        ExcelApp.Quit();        
    }            
    return Protected;
} 


You're using Excel interop to drive Excel. There won't be any Excel instance installed on the database server. SSIS can already read from Excel files.

Does this answer your question? how to check Excel Workbook or sheet is password protected or not?

What are you trying to do? Trying to read multiple files that may or may not be password protected is just bad file management. SSIS is an ETL tool, not a file checker. If you want to check all Excel files in a folder it would be a lot faster to write a C# program using eg EPPlus or ExcelDataReader that checks whether the files can be opened without a password without installing Excel. All the Excel libraries in NuGet are so light compared to Excel itself that you can quickly search a lot of files and even parallelize the code with Parallel.ForEachAsync
